# How to fetch a word following other word in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a file with content

```
SQL> SELECT 'conn '||u.name ||'/abcd123'||chr(10) ||'create '||DECODE(U.NAME,'PUBLIC','public ')||'database link ' || L.NAME|| ' connect to ' || L.USERID || ' identified by values '''||
  2  L.PASSWORDX||''' using ''' || L.host || ''''||';' FROM system.xpr_link$ L, system.xpr_user$ U WHERE L.OWNER# = U.USER# and u.name not in ('APPS','SYS','SYSTEM') order by l.OWNER#;
conn GESADM/abcd123                                                                                             


create database link ODSPUSH.CISCO.COM connect to XXDM identified by values '056D98F3367CAC4478383FFB673E4D22329E172F2B25778BE3' using 'TS3ODS';                                                        

conn GESADM/abcd123                                                                                                                                                                                     
create database link TS3CFN.CISCO.COM connect to GESADM identified by values '05A0E92F39E91BA002F98DE9A46FC72B31572483E12D3AAB67' using 'TS3CFN';                                                       


create database link SYNSTG.CISCO.COM connect to SYN_CLNTSRV identified by values '066C10B37E3A3D0A3AA96B9FDE063585B662E3921F3C3F5A3E224BD4394A7BD659DAD174ABDE36594E7F3B466D6B0DCF78F13D75BA3B47090D295
8F8604E637462A2A41F74458E0C0EB649EE9A537AD2AE109A20B2DA09E5F9A28D666B8980651B79C0E76BBD6CBBCD169645970FDD615291C8557DBC79F527BF32E14A845025' using 'SYNSTG';
```

How to get the word following the word "values" using regex in Perl.

Comment: You have to have a go and coding something first, and then show us what you've got, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: This might help http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html

Answer (score 0):

Every place in your sample string where "`values`" occurs, the word preceding it (*as your post requested before it was edited*) is "`by`", so I don't know how useful it can be to capture each word that is followed by "`values`".

Nevertheless, that's what you seem to be asking for (*before the edit reversed the meaning*), and here's one way to do it:

```
while( $string =~ m/\b(\p{Alpha}+)\b\s*values/g ) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

...will produce the following output:

```
by
by
by
by
```

If, on the other hand, you intended to say something like "the quoted numeric value following the word 'values'" (*which is similar to what your edited post is now requesting*), this will work:

```
while( $string =~ m/values\s*'([^']+)'/g ) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

...which produces...

```
056D98F3367CAC4478383FFB673E4D22329E172F2B25778BE3
05A0E92F39E91BA002F98DE9A46FC72B31572483E12D3AAB67
066C10B37E3A3D0A3AA96B9FDE063585B662E3921F3C3F5A3E224BD4394A7BD659DAD174ABDE36594E7F3B466D6B0DCF78F13D75BA3B47090D295
8F8604E637462A2A41F74458E0C0EB649EE9A537AD2AE109A20B2DA09E5F9A28D666B8980651B79C0E76BBD6CBBCD169645970FDD615291C8557DBC79F527BF32E14A845025
```

Comment: David, I believe he meant 'following' instead of 'followed by'. I have edited his post accordingly.

Comment: You may be right, but that constitutes a radical change, as it reverses the original meaning.  But I'll update my post to include that possibility (since it's probably accurate).

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you are trying to extract strings from a text file? Do I have that right?

If you're talking about the string after the word `values`:

```
while ($subject =~ m/values '\K[^']*/g) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vS1xD1).

If you're talking about the string after `using`:

```
while ($subject =~ m/values '[^']*' using '\K[^']*/g) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cN9mH9).

Let me know which one you want, and I'll add an explanation.